# Error:Android Source Generator: [project] AndroidManifest.xml file not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

i clone  [couchbase-turorial](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-lite-tutorial-android.git). But i got error in android studio AndroidManifest.xml not found. It is gradle project. I insert the following code

```
 sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'HelloWorld/HelloWorld/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

in build.gradle but it is not work. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553060/errorandroid-source-generator-randomproject-androidmanifest-xml-file-not-fou) is very relevant. This is my [build.gradle](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-lite-tutorial-android/blob/master/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/build.gradle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to modify the build.gradle file. It seems like you may have imported the /couchbase-lite-tutorial-android folder rather than the /couchbase-lite-tutorial-android/HelloWorld folder into Android Studio.